# Passing Data Between abstract classes

Tags: c++, object-oriented-analysis

I'm looking for opinions on the best OO way to accomplish what I am about to describe. I'm writing what is going to become an event system for games and the like and I want it to be as extensible as possible, as such there is a lot of abstract classes. Two of these are monitors which are assigned to monitor one event, and callbacks, which wrap the function pointer to be called should the event take place. The issue arises when I want to send the data that the callback needs. The data that will be sent is going to be sub-class specific (depending on the function signature) and stored in the subclassed monitor. I want to be able to pass this data along to the callback before calling execute, but since everything is abstract from the perspective of the monitor this is difficult. I'm looking for suggestions on how to do this in the best OO way possible, as of yet I haven't come up with anything I'm too fond of. Since the callbacks are sent to another class to actually be dispatched the data needs to end up inside them at some point.

For reference, the monitor abstract class

```
#pragma once

#include "DIVE_GUI_Types.h"
#include "DIVE_GUI_Callback.h"
#include "DIVE_GUI_Event_Dispatcher.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>

/*
Class to monitor events to be handled by the event system.
*/

class DIVE_GUI_Event_Monitor
{
private:
    friend class                                        DIVE_GUI_Kernel;
    DIVE_GUI_Event_Dispatcher*                          m_Dispatcher;
    static DIVE_HANDLE                                  m_Active_GUI;

protected:
    const std::string                                   m_Event_ID;
    std::map<DIVE_HANDLE, DIVE_GUI_Callback*>           m_GUI_Map;
    virtual bool Dispatch() = 0;

public:
    void Update();
    std::string Get_Event_ID() const { return m_Event_ID; }
    DIVE_GUI_Event_Monitor(const std::string& id) : m_Event_ID(id) { }
    void Add_Callback(DIVE_HANDLE, DIVE_GUI_Callback* function);
};
```

And the callback abstract class

```
#pragma once

/*
Abstract class representing a wrapper for a callback function as per the Command design     pattern.
*/

class DIVE_GUI_Callback
{
public:
    virtual void Excecute_Callback() const = 0;
};
```

Any and all opinions / suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood you, this data should be supplied to callback constructor. Suppose you have `Callback1` and `Callback2` derived from `DIVE_GUI_Callback`. So the code could look like:

```
DIVE_GUI_Event_Monitor* monitor; 
monitor->Add_Callback(Callback1(specific_data_1));
monitor->Add_Callback(Callback2(specific_data_2));
```

This specific data then will be used in `Excecute_Callback()`.

Comment: The issue with this is that the data needs to be updated essentially every frame, unless the callback had references to all of it passed in the constructor I suppose. I'm not sure how good of a design that is.

Comment: @Pat: in this case it should be passed to `Excecute_Callback()` or Callback should be able to ask for this data